"T" shortcut hijacked by addon?
Blender 3.6.5 The "T" key (for Toolbar) when pressed does not work. Instead  a message: "You cant Split this area in Fullscreen" What's the Process to find which addon is using "T" and put it back to default to open the Toolbar?

If you go to the Preferences( F4  ->  P ), Keymap tab, switch the search to Key-Binding and search for the key, you can find out what that key is assigned to and possibly fix it the way you want:


~ Thank you, MACHINE TOOLS addon was the culprit.
